# Determine kernel of Vandermonde matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}x_1^0&&x_1^1&&\ldots&&x_1^n\\x_2^0&&x_2^1&&\ldots&&x_2^n\\\vdots&&\vdots&&\ldots&&\vdots\\x_m^0&&x_m^1&&\ldots&&x_m^n\end{pmatrix}$$

$n<m-1$ and the $x_i$ are pairwise distinct

What is the kernel of the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 2):

Let me enlarge the matrix to be quadratic: Define
$$
A'= \pmatrix{ x_1^0  & \dots & x_1^{m-1} \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ x_m^0 & \dots & x_m^{m-1}}
$$
then $\det A'\ne0$, the columns of $A'$ are linearly independent, thus the columns of $A$ are linearly independent as well (as they are a subset of the columns of $A'$).
Hence
$$
\ker A=\{0\}.
$$

Comment: $A'$ has $m$ rows and $m+1$ columns so it isn't quadratic

Comment: @user711482 thanks, corrected

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the $n\times n$ square matrix that agrees with $A$ on first $n$ rows, it is non-singular if $x_i$ are pairwise distinct, so it has rank = column rank = $n+1$

Now, the A must have row rank $\ge n+1$, and since row rank = column rank, and column rank $\le n+1$, hence its row rank is $n+1$, columns are linearly independent, hence kernel is the trivial space.

Comment: What do you mean by 'new A'? $A$ is not a square matrix. I know that a square Vandermonde matrix has determinant $\neq 0$ if all $x_i$ are pairwise distinct